# Script that list file names by first letter bash type

Tags: ls

I need a script that takes input from the user which specifies the first letter of the file names to be displayed, so that only file names starting with the letter specified are listed.
I only need to print out file size and file name and have all of it to be sent to a `.txt` file all in one step.

To make the output text go to a certain directory just point to it like so?
`/ect/myscrpits/output.txt`

Here is what I have done so far

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == " " ]
then
echo "Usage: Type a single letter at the end for a list of files that start with that letter. The list is sorted from largest to smallest."
echo "Example: ./bwalla_.sh a"

else
while
read letter
ls -l "$letter*" |awk '{print $5,$9;}' > bwalla_output.txt

fi
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: indeed I used this command ls d* -lS |awk '{print $5,$9;}' I just dont know how to make this a variable in a script that a user can enter

Answer (score 2):

Use read function to get the user input, save the input into a variable and display the files within the variable with ls.

e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin
echo "Type the letter: "
read letter
ls -l "$letter"* | awk '{print $5,$9}' > output.txt
```

Comment: You mean `ls -l "$letter"*`.  Or, better yet, `ls -ld "$letter"*`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a facile solution. The input from the user goes where `a` is below. Replace this letter as necessary.

```
ls a*
```

Yep. That's it. :/

Comment: ls d* -lS |awk '{print $5,$9;}' is the command I used to show only the file size and the name that in this case is any file that starts with a d

Comment: It seems that you want more than your (original) question asked for. Please edit it with the desired output.